# How to remove file from git commit

Tags: git

By accident I added a large file to my git commit, and I'm now trying to remove it again.

from https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/ 
I was inspired to try this

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .ntvs_analysis.dat' \--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But i end op with

```
>_
```

I was expecting a $ instead. If I enter a `'`

I get this error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I have maded some commits afterwards that I would like to keep. How do I remove the large file from my commit, so I can upload to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you escaped the single quote to start the command, so that the `--index-filter` option received the single argument `'git`. The `>_` is the continuation prompt when you ended the line without closing the *unescaped* single quote that you intended as the closing quote. The error occurred due to the `git` misunderstanding the resulting sequence of arguments. The correct command is simply

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .ntvs_analysis.dat' --prune-empty
```

(Removed the backslash prior to the first single quote and the `--prune-empty` option. I removed the `--tag-filter` entirely, since I wasn't sure how that was needed, although `--tag-filter cat -- --all` was almost certainly incorrect.)

Answer (score 3):

In order not to lose the file you added you can follow the following steps:

1. `git reset --soft HEAD~1` - this will reset the branch to the previous snapshot while leaving all files staged
2. `git reset HEAD file_to_remove` - this will remove test.txt from staging
3. `git commit -a -m "commit message"` - re-commit your staged changes without the file to remove

Just one important note - the above assume that your commit was not pushed to the public repository (in which case using git reset is not recommended)

Comment: If i try to push to github I get a "remote: error: File .ntvs_analysis.dat is 100.15 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file
size limit of 100 MB" error

Answer (score 0):

1. Revert to previous git commit using

   ```
   # Moves pointer back to previous HEAD
   git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
   ```
2. And simply remove your file

   ```
   rm <filename>
   ```
3. Then again commit your changes back

   ```
   git commit -a
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but by doing this wont I loose all my changes?

Comment: I don't think he wants to remove the file from his filesystem, so `rm <filename>` would not be a wise move

Comment: The file is auto generated, and I have added it to .gitignore in a later commit. So it is okay if it is deleted from the file system

Comment: @CruelIO: Yes your changes won't get affected. It'll just uncommit (revert) back to previous commit. (i.e. the state just before your have done your last commit).

Comment: @ParagTyagi-morpheus- But my history is 1) added file. 2) edit files 3) commit) 4) added large file. 5)commit 6) changes other files 7) commit. I would like not to loose the changes made in 6)

Comment: If you've added it to `.gitignore` then your don't have to remove since it won't be now in your `untracked` or `unstaged`. So `.gitignore`  will do here for you

Comment: If you want that file in your local but not on your server or your hosting space (viz. GitHub, Bitbucket) and `.gitignore` is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

1. Revert to last commit

   ```
   git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
   ```
2. Remove file from the staged file list

   ```
   git restore --staged file-name
   ```
3. Add new commit

   ```
   git commit -m "commit-msg"
   ```